# Spring Boot Reactive repository test fails always, due to duplicated key exception

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, reactive-programming, data-integrity

I am trying to test my ReactiveCrudRepository, but my findByName method always fails, due to a org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException. It seems like the sequence is providing always the same IDs for any entities. I am not sure if the database is acting weired or my test is weired.
If I save one person entity it seems to be fine but if I am trying to save more than one, I am getting the exception.

I am using a Postgres 13 database and SpringBoot 2.3.4.
My table create statement looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('reactive.person_id_seq'::regclass),
    last_name varying(255),
    first_name character varying(255),
    email character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The repository test class looks like that:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.r2dbc.DataR2dbcTest;
import alone.at.home.reactive.entity.PersonEntity;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

@DataR2dbcTest
@Slf4j
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepo;

@BeforeEach
void clean() {
    personRepo.deleteAll().subscribe();
}

@Test
void testFindByNameMethod() {
    
    PertsonEntity person = PersonEntity.builder()
        .lastName("QWERTZ")
        .firstName("Test")
        .email("QWERTZ@Test.org")
        .build();
    
    PertsonEntity person2 = PersonEntity.builder()
        .lastName("QWERTZ")
        .firstName("Test2")
        .email("QWERTZ2@Test2.org")
        .build();
    
    personRepo.save(person)
        .doOnSuccess(onSuccess -> log.info("Person saved successfully: {}", onSuccess))
        .doOnError(onError -> log.info("Person save operation not successful: {}", onError.getMessage(), onError))
        .subscribe();
    personRepo.save(person2)
        .doOnSuccess(onSuccess -> log.info("Person saved successfully: {}", onSuccess))
        .doOnError(onError -> log.info("Person save operation not successful: {}", onError.getMessage(), onError))
        .subscribe();
    

    personRepo.findByName("QWERTZ")
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectNextCount(2)
        .verifyComplete();
}
```

}

PersonEntity class:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor  
@NoArgsConstructor 
@Table("person")
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private double email;
}
```

MyCRUD repositoy:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import import alone.at.home.reactive.entity.PersonEntity;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<PersonEntity, Long>{

    Mono<List<PersonEntity>> findByName(String name);

}
```

The entire exception stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: executeMany; SQL [INSERT INTO person (id, last_name, first_name, email) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)]; duplicate key violated unique-vonstraint »person_pkey«; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlDataIntegrityViolationException: [23505] duplicate key value violated Unique-Constraint »person_pkey«
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.support.R2dbcExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(R2dbcExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:78) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.support.AbstractFallbackR2dbcExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackR2dbcExceptionTranslator.java:67) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient.translateException(DefaultDatabaseClient.java:264) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient.lambda$inConnectionMany$8(DefaultDatabaseClient.java:200) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$29(Flux.java:6539) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorResume$30(Flux.java:6592) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.deferredError(FluxUsingWhen.java:408) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$RollbackInner.onComplete(FluxUsingWhen.java:485) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2016) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2016) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1824) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:314) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1824) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:314) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerInner.onComplete(SimpleDequePool.java:555) ~[reactor-pool-0.1.6.RELEASE.jar:0.1.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:135) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueuePoolRecyclerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:667) ~[reactor-pool-0.1.6.RELEASE.jar:0.1.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97) [reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onError(MonoIgnoreElements.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxFilterFuseable.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxFilterFuseable.java:375) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:326) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:243) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:346) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:403) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreElements.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:298) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:255) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onError(FluxUsingWhen.java:374) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:834) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:600) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:580) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerError(FluxFlatMap.java:855) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:1006) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onError(FluxHandle.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeUntil$TakeUntilPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxTakeUntil.java:77) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:86) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$Conversation.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:725) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:976) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:850) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:757) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:845) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:256) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar:0.9.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:362) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar:0.9.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar:0.9.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.12.RELEASE.jar:0.9.12.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlDataIntegrityViolationException: duplicate key value violated Unique-Constraint »person_pkey«
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:91) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory.handleErrorResponse(ExceptionFactory.java:110) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlResult.lambda$map$1(PostgresqlResult.java:100) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

These are my first steps in reactive programming with SpringBoot and I am thankful for every helpful hint.

If you need some more information just let me know.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because your id is long, not Long.

Having it as long, it always has a value, and because Spring Data R2DBC has no idea about your schema and that it will be automatically generated, it includes the value in the insert statement.

If you switch it to Long, as it will be null if not set, it should not include it in the insert statement (or at worse set it to null) and the value should be generated by the database because of the default value you configured.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. You saved my day. :)